# Upgrade to Windows 8 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, delete, windows-8

Windows are now selling versions of windows for £25.00. I want to update and get rid of ubuntu. How do I do this? And will it be comptable for ubuntu? I hope so.

Pls help.

(Oh, and I am using an E-System 1201 laptop that is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It also has a brokencount>0' error. I hope that error does not affect the system upgrading.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS upgrade is for Windows 7 not for Ubuntu!